# How to repeatedly add +1 to variable on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have defined a `function plusOne()` which is supposed to add +1 to a variable (and then set the `innerHTML` of an element to be that variable). The function is called when a `button` is clicked.

However, the adding of +1 only works once. How do I have to change my function in order to add +1 to the variable every time the button is clicked?

Here's how my function and HTML are looking right now, along with a JSFiddle:

```js
function plusOne() {
  var number = 1;
  var count = document.getElementById('count');

  number++;
  count.innerHTML = number;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="plusOne()">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

Link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/johschmoll/hLymhak7/1/

Comment: Move `var number = 1;` outside of the function. You're resetting it to 1 each time you call the function.

Comment: @Andy Ahhh, I see. Dumb mistake, should've figured that one out by myself. Thanks.

Comment: Define `var number = 1;` as a global scope or use `closure`

Comment: you should also do the same with `var count = document.getElementById('count');` you dont need to call it everytime

Comment: Close voters - this is not a typographical error. This is a conceptual problem in understanding that many people might repeat when new to programming. The typo reason is not a valid CV reason here. However, it is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Minimal solution: Move the state variable outside of the click handler's scope

Change your JavaScript to put the `number` variable outside of the click handler. Otherwise, you are resetting the `number` variable to 1 everytime the click handler is called.

```
var number = 1;

function plusOne() {
  var count = document.getElementById('count');

  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/6/

## Move the element reference outside the click handler's scope

It is also a good idea to keep the element reference outside of the click handler's scope if the element is never destroyed.

```
var number = 1;
var count = document.getElementById('count');

function plusOne() {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

DOM query lookups are cheap nowadays, but a lot of them will negatively affect your app's performance.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/8/

## Make the element dependency explicit

We can even pass the `count` element to the click handler to make it easier to test.

### JavaScript

```
var number = 1;

function plusOne(count) {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="plusOne(count)">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

The `span` element is actually assigned to a global variable which is within the scope of the `button` element just like the `plusOne` click handler. This means that in all examples, we could just as easily have used `count` or `window.count` to access the `span` element.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/12/

## Best practice: Add as event listener

It is not recommended to bind the click handler by using the `onclick` attribute of the `button` element. One of the reasons is that we are only ever allowed to add one `onclick` handler, which is not the case with `Element#addEventListener`.

### HTML

```
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="incrementor">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var number = 1;
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var incrementor = document.getElementById('incrementor');
incrementor.addEventListener('click', plusOne);

function plusOne() {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

[See more discussions about onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871640/1071200)

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/13/

## Combine best practice with explicit element dependency

We can add a click listener that also passes the `count` element explicitly to the `plusOne` function.

```
var number = 1;
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var incrementor = document.getElementById('incrementor');
incrementor.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    plusOne(count);
});

function plusOne(count) {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

Now we are one step closer to maintainable code that is easily tested.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/14/

## Final solution that is maintainable and easily tested

We can complete our solution by making the second dependency explicit, namely the `number` state variable.

When we pass this variable to the `plusOne` function, we now have a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) which makes it easy to test and reason about.

### HTML

```
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="incrementor">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var number = 1;
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var incrementor = document.getElementById('incrementor');
incrementor.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
    number = plusOne(count, number);
});

function plusOne(count, number) {
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
  
  return number;
}
```

While this is more verbose, the dependendencies are clear and the actual business logic, i.e. the `plusOne` function, can be extracted to a separate file and unit tested to verify that it does what it is supposed to.

### Test suite

```
import { plusOne } from './plus-one';

describe('plusOne', () => {
  let countElement;
  let initialState;
  let state;

  beforeEach(() => {
    initialState = 1;
    state = initialState;
    countElement = {
      textContent: initialState.toString(),
    };
  })

  it('returns an incremented state', () => {
    state = plusOne(countElement, state);
    expect(state).toBe(initialState + 1);
  });

  it('does not mutate the state', () => {
    plusOne(countElement, state);
    expect(state).toBe(initialState);
  })

  it('reflects the state in the count element', () => {
    state = plusOne(countElement, state);
    expect(countElement.textContent).toEqual(state.toString());
  });
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/15/

Test suite example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-javascript-jquery-repeatedly-add-1-to-variable-o?file=src%2Fplus-one.spec.ts

## Anti-pattern: Keep state in DOM

A lot of web apps keep the state in the DOM. While this is easy and we have less mutable state in our code, usually we want access to the state in multiple places of our apps.

Having to extract the state from the DOM in all places where we need it is not how it is supposed to be. We are supposed to keep our business logic in JavaScript and let the DOM reflect the state, not the other way around.

It also adds to a tight coupling to the DOM, making it more difficult to maintain and test.

```
// Keeping state in DOM is NOT recommended, but here we go...
var count = document.getElementById('count');

function plusOne() {
  var number = Number(count.textContent);
  number++;
  count.textContent = number.toString();
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hLymhak7/9/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!-- Using inline js-->
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('count').innerHTML++">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function plusOne(){
var count = document.getElementById('count');
count.innerHTML++
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="count">1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="plusOne()">
    +
  </button>
</div>
```